# How to modify the field values of newly created Item/Page from sitecore Webservice

Tags: web-services, sitecore, xmlnode

By using Sitecore webservice I created a new Page Item as Below.

```
var scClient = new VisualSitecoreServiceSoapClient();
// another code
var xmlNode = scClient.AddFromTemplate(parentId, pagetemplateId,itemName,database,credentials)
```

I cannot use the Database Items, just the web service.

From xmlNode I get the newly created GUID/Id. How do I edit the fields of newly created Item from the webservice only?

Comment: You might want to take a look at  InsertXML method here - http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/65/sitecore_web_service_sc65-a4.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Save()` method like this:

```cs
string itemId = // id from AddFromTemplate() xmlNode 
string fieldId = "{some-id-of-the-field}"; // id of the field

XDocument fieldXml = new XDocument(
    new XElement("sitecore",
        new XElement("field",
            new XAttribute("itemid", itemId),
            new XAttribute("language", "en"),
            new XAttribute("version", 1),
            new XAttribute("fieldid", fieldId),
            new XElement("value", "new value of the field")
        )
    )
);

XElement fieldResponse = scClient.Save(fieldXml, "web", credentials);
```

---

**EDIT:**

In response to your comment: No, you cannot use field name instead of field id. Still you can use `GetItemFields` method exposed in `VisualSitecoreServiceSoapClient` to list all the fields of the item and then determine what is the id of the field with given name:

```cs
public XmlDocument GetItemFields(string id, string language, string version, bool allFields, string databaseName, Credentials credentials)
```

Comment: Thanks Maras, I am able to modify the field by using your code. Is there a way I can modify using field name instead of field id?

Comment: You cannot use field name. See updated answer with the explanation

Comment: Make Sense Maras, I'll do as you suggested. Thanks again for your help.